# Center content in div Framework 7

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

In my grid layout, using Framework 7, i need to center a link that is a button located in a row. I've tried to set `justified-content: center;` creating a new class colled `center` but i see that this CSS property is overridden:
`justified-content: space-between;` from default Framework 7 CSS file.
This is my page content:

```
<div data-page="scanQR" class="page">
    <!-- Scrollable page content-->
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">
          <div class="row center">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <img src="img/pagopa.png" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row center">
              <div class="col-100.tablet-33">
                <p><a href="#" class="button mybtn" id="scan">Scan QR Code</a></p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can i get that link centered in my view?

Comment: I see your last question picked up on your invalid class too

Comment: That's not an invalid class! It's a Framework 7 css class! @Pete

Comment: It's a css class but you cannot use it like that in html, it's invalid for where you have put it - you cannot have `.` in a class name in the html attribute - you have it without the dot and then in the css you reference it with the dot (which denotes class)

Comment: @Pete Can you explain better? I have linked the proper css file in my html.

Comment: I think you need to learn more about classes and styles before you continue as this is what will be causing a lot of your issues and browsers not behaving as you expect

Comment: That was a typo error, i have removed it. @Pete

Comment: Have a [read of this](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/) and notice the difference between the css selectors (with {}) and the css attributes put into the html - you will see no dots or hashes are ever used in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in `<div class=".col-100.tablet-33">` classes.

- Change it to: `<div class="col-100 tablet-33">`

Snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/1.5.2/css/framework7.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div data-page="scanQR" class="page">
  <!-- Scrollable page content-->
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block">
      <div class="content-block-inner">
        <div class="row center">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <img src="img/pagopa.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row center">
          <div class="col-100 tablet-33">
            <p><a href="#" class="button mybtn" id="scan">Scan QR Code</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This CSS property is disabled in Framework 7 so I can't use it

Comment: Added framework css file to the snippet and tweaked your classes, seems to do the trick.